# How do I delete a row without having the id in url?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, delete-row

I have a form for adding aanbiedingen (offers) from companies. I use three tables for this:

```
Aanbiedingen
- - - - - - -
idaanbiedingen //id
Aanbieding //offername
Omschrijving //description
Prijs //price
Conditie //condition

Bedrijfaanbiedingen
- - - - - - - - - - 
idbedrijfaanbiedingen //id
idaanbiedingen // offers id
idbedrijven // company id
idfotoaanbiedingen // photo id

fotoaanbiedingen
- - - - - - - - -
idfotoaanbiedingen //id
fotonaam // photo name (this is the file_name)
```

I am able to delete the data from the tables: Aanbiedingen and Bedrijfaanbiedingen. I use the id in the url to delete them. I use the idaanbiedingen in both tables to delete the data.

**Question**

How can I delete the data from the `fotoaanbiedingen` without having the idaanbiedingen in that table?
I don't get how to do this. It looks almost impossible. I thought about working with a join on the idfotoaanbiedingen in `bedrijfaanbiedingen` but I don't know how to do that.

My model looks like this:

```
function deleteaanbieding($id)
{
    $this->db->where('idaanbiedingen', $id);
    $this->db->delete('bedrijfaanbiedingen');
    $this->db->where('idaanbiedingen', $id);
    $this->db->delete('Aanbiedingen');
    redirect('members/aanbiedingen');
}
```

The $id field is: `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);`

How can I add the function to delete from `fotoaanbiedingen`?

Comment: Normally, you could do a delete join sql query but I don't think this is supported by Codeigniters active record. You may have to revert to using `$this->db->query()`;

Comment: If your not doing a soft delete (setting a delete flag in the db), you could also create a cascade delete relationship between your tables in mysql, and rely on that to delete the records for you. Assuming it's a one to many relationship.

Comment: Could one of you provide an example using SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a standard mysql query it would look something like this.

```
delete Aanbiedingen,Bedrijfaanbiedingen,fotoaanbiedingen 
from Bedrijfaanbiedingen
inner join Aanbiedingen ON Aanbiedingen.idaanbiedingen = Bedrijfaanbiedingen.idaanbiedingen
inner join fotoaanbiedingen ON fotoaanbiedingen.idfotoaanbiedingen = Bedrijfaanbiedingen.idfotoaanbiedingen 
where Bedrijfaanbiedingen.idaanbiedingen= {the id}
```

Please try the code, note this code is not tested. You can convert it to active record if you want, basically table `Bedrijfaanbiedingen` has something in common with table `fotoaanbiedingen` which is the `idfotoaanbiedingen`, you just need to join them.

Comment: This worked like a charm. thankyou!. I changed {the id} with $id and It worked. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have ID field then you can delete using other fields if possible in your situation.

Check if it works for you:

```
$this->db->join('fotoaanbiedingen', 'fotoaanbiedingen.idfotoaanbiedingen = Bedrijfaanbiedingen.idfotoaanbiedingen');
```

Comment: Nah I just can't. If you look at the first two tables. They have idaanbiedingen. but the third table doesn't. So how could I delete that? I guess using the join from `bedrijfaanbiedingen` ?

Comment: So how do I use that to delete the data?

Comment: I already tried it with that join. but What is the delete function after joining those id's ?

Answer (score 0):

First I think that it would make your life easier Bedrijfaanbiedingen and fotoaanbiedingen were linked in the other side (fotoaanbiedingen would have a foreign key : idbedrijfaanbiedingen)

For your problem, you should consider using the where_in() activerecord function (see the doc, activerecord section). You have to have an array of idfotoaanbiedingen.

For example, if you have a idbedrijfaanbiedingen you should try something like (the following code is at the beginning of your method):

```
$this->db->select('idfotoaanbiedingen');
$this->db->from('Bedrijfaanbiedingen');
$this->db->where('idbedrijfaanbiedingen',$yourId);
$query = $this->db->get(); //getting the photo id out of the Bedrijfaanbiedingen table

//not sure about the result array, you should treat it better before entering it in argument of this method
$this->db->where_in('idfotoaanbiedingen',$query->result_array());  
$this->db->delete('fotoaanbiedingen');
```